# Selenium remote web driver can't start

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm struggling with this for 2 days. I googled and found this issue appearing quite often to the people. I tried their solutions but they are not working for me.

I have `selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar` and I started hub and node in separate cmd windows with these commands:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar \ -role hub -port 4444

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS -remoteHost http://localhost:5555
```

then I try to create remote web driver with this code:

```
public class probna {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty(
                    "webdriver.chrome.driver",
                     "D:\\CODE\\proba2\\demos\\src\\main\\java\\com\\nortal\\demos\\chromedriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();    
            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), caps);
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

and I get this error all the time no matter what I changed:

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
```

Comment: is it works for you if you use different browser instead of chrome? And is it strange, that you have a capability for IE. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: sorry about that line for IE. I forgot to comment it - will edit the question. I tried chrome and IE and getting same error for both.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you if you run

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role hub -port 4444

instead of this:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar \ -role hub -port 4444

?